# How to create a changelog of periodical rest api calls in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm struggling with following idea and need your help:

I'm thinking about periodically calling a object based REST API
and ingesting only the diff between the latest two calls.

Why? Because the source system is not event driven (returns all data - HTTP GET resource), but the target system is (needs only the updates between the latest two calls - HTTP POST update).

My first idea was to use Apache Kafka, because of order guarantee and so I could build a consumer who consumes the latest two events, but I'm not quite happy with the idea of referencing the whole payload in every message and diffing everything to send the HTTP POST in the end.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you really just want either a KV store or a TSDB. A changelog in Kafka typically means infinite retention periods

Comment: Somehow yes, you're right. I was just thinking about if I could make use of apache kafka in this scenario and also to use it in future. Infinite retention must not be, 30 days would also do the trick.

Comment: Another point that isn't really possible with Kafka as a queue alone is that you need a reference to the previous record for every new record. You might only be able to get that to work with a Kafka Streams KTable processor, but again, that's an external process and it's not really clear if that's what you really want